# Nvidia Physx on iPhone

Tags: iphone, nvidia, physx

is it possible? if yes, how?

if not, how does unity3d make it happen?

Comment: From this list seems the answer is no: http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_gpus.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Physx has a software only implementation, and a hardware assisted one.